# Padding percent in container-fluid in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm try add padding-left and padding-right to my container-fluid in Bootstrap. But when I to Reload the page, my padding work only after the end of loading page. (U use in project: Bootstrap,Razor, DurandalJS, Knockout, ASP.NET MVC)
First my page looks like this:

[image]

Then, after 2-3 second, my page is becoming as necessary

[image]

Code of global page:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="page-host" id="content-host" data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance' }"></div>
</div>
```

This is CSS style:

```
.page-host {
position: relative;
left: 0;
top:30px;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
padding-left: 5% !important;
padding-right: 5% !important;
```

}
How to make my container-fluid with padding-left: 5% and padding-right: 5% when loading the page?

Comment: Do you have some code to help us help you?

Comment: A lot of files in the project. I'm afraid that has no idea how to show them all.

Comment: How do you implement the CSS? In `<script></script>` or in a seperate `.css` file? Where on the page do you implement it? header / footer / body / etc ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/durandal.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/newStyle.css" /> But it's not 
the sequence of addition my CSS style. I'm was try change sequence of addition. Problem is remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a row you need to put a column as well for the padding to go back to normal.  Even if there is nothing inside of the col, I believe it is required.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div> 
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="page-host" id="content-host" data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance' }">

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its relay works. But why I need to use col-*-*, if I use col inside page-host in another cshtml file?

Comment: Best answer I have is that a .row adds a negative pixel padding to whatever your column padding is.  If your column padding is 15px (default), then your .row will have a -15px padding.  The specifics of why they do it are listed here: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro)